# Is it possible to make Inkscape autotrace PNG to SVG, but from the command line?

Tags: svg, scripting, vector-graphics, inkscape, image-conversion

I want to automate "raster to vector" conversions. PNG to SVG. (most Qs here on SO are the other way around)

I have tried the old command line tool  *autotrace* on Linux, but I could not get it to run. I've tried to install a package, and to compile it from the source. Nope.

Then I've realised that Inkscape has "autotrace" now integrated in its codebase. I'd like to convert simple sketches from PNG to SVG.

And I want to do this in a Bash for-loop , with different autotrace settings (number of passes; ignore Speckles with max X pixels width) etc.

I've tried the "*action*" command-line option

```
inkscape --without-gui --actions="file-open:my.png"
```

and this brings up the small "png bitmap image import" dialog, waiting for me to confirm.

Also I've tried the *verb* command line option

```
inkscape --with-gui  --verb="FileImport:my.png"
```

and this opens the large "Select file to import" dialog (ignoring my `--verb` argument)

At this point I gave up.

I want Inkscape to import a PNG picture, autotrace it with some settings, save it as SVG. Perhaps, beofre saving, duplicate the traced layer, lock the imported background layer, rename the layers from path-12345 to "tracesettings-x-y-z" etc.

(my final goal is to permute the tracing settings, to find good ones for my use-case, but that's not the focus of this question)

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133437/inkscape-bash-commant-to-automate-image-trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inkscape is using [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) and [autotrace](https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace) to trace bitmap images into vector formats such as SVG and PDF.

Let's assume you have an image: `foo.png` that you want to trace to SVG using potrace:

- First, you need to convert your image to a bitmap format (BMP).
- Invoke the `potrace` command

```sh
# I am using ImageMagick convert command to convert PNG to BMP
convert foo.png foo.bmp

# Invoke potrace command with SVG backend
potrace -b svg foo.bmp
```

The result will be: `foo.svg`.

Comment: This seems like a feasible alternative, just as good, thanks. -- I think Inkscape also contains autotrace now. I've read it somewhere, cannot remember where. One of the comments in [this thread on graphic-design.se](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133437/inkscape-bash-commant-to-automate-image-trace) (pointed to by Sphinxxx) says to too.

Comment: @knb: I have updated the answer. You can download autotrace from their github repo: https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace/releases